# Can I regenerate access token and refresh token pair if my client secret expires?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have an App registered in Azure and the client secret has expired. For the same client secret can the access token be regenerated using the refresh token last received?

Just to be clear, the ask here is for access token when the client secret expires and not when the access token expires.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that, If the **`client_secret`** is expired you cannot generate access and refresh tokens. One must create the new secret and then try to generate the tokens.

Using the expired **`client_secret`** leads to failure in generation of tokens and will get **error** like below:

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I generated **access and refresh token** using below parameters in Postman:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

To refresh the access token, I used the below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientId
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:refreshtoken
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Comment: This behaviour is required by the OAuth RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6. "If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described in Section 3.2.1."